# Convert CURL request to AJAX request

Tags: ajax, curl

I need to convert following CURL request into HTML. the application hasn't given any documentation for AJAX on their website

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: 
xxxx" 
"https://developers.abcdef.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=000000"
```

So far i keep getting following response

```
{"code":403,"status":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid API Key"}
```

Okay, apparently i didn't make it clear enough. I get a proper response when i fill in a form on application website. They give me response and above mentioned CURL request in code boxes.

I get the above mentioned response when i try to implement it myself using AJAX

Comment: If you're getting that error from the server for your CURL request, switching to AJAX client-side isn't going to change that.

Comment: @David I get a proper response when i fill in a form on application website. They give me response and above mentioned CURL request in code boxes.

I get the above mentioned response when i try to implement it myself using AJAX

Comment: There is no such implementation attempt in the question.  We'll need to see the code you're writing in order to help with it.

Comment: You can only make AJAX request, given that, the application allows cross-origin requests and there is no mixed content. Once you confirm that, the answer below should work. All in all, you are better off using CURL request, as CURL was designed for this. AJAX does not really play well on this kind of cross domain requests.

Answer (score -1):

your response `{"code":403,"status":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid API Key"}` clearly shows you are either `missing api key` / or `sending invalid api key` with the ajax request.

try after adding the api key to the below request format.

`$.ajax({
  method : 'GET', 
  url : 'http://your-url.com',
  headers : { 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'user-key' : 'YOUR API KEY' },
  success : function(data){  console.log(data); }
});`